# dataloader from command line fails to override the property-value pair specified in process-conf.xml

Tags: data-loader

Using dataloader from the command line, I'm trying to override the property-value pair I've specified in the process-conf.xml with that specified on the command line.

I'm hoping to get this to work as described in the section **Property value interactions** in this dataloader documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line - which states

> Any property-value pairs included as part of the command line are used in place of any other specifications in the other files.

**The details:**

In the `process-conf.xml` I have the following property-value pair specified:

```
entry key="dataAccess.name" value="D:\Batch\Salesforce\Data\DataToSF\Store__c.csv"
```

When I run dataloader from the command line as follows this works as expected and loads data from the Store__c.csv:

```
cmd> process.bat D:\Batch\Salesforce\DataLoaderConfig Upsert_Store__c
```

However if I then rename the csv to be `Store__c_20160702.csv` and  try to load the file using the following command (i.e. including the additional parameter which I expect to override the dataAccess.name property-value pair specified in the `process-conf.xml`):

```
cmd> process.bat D:\Batch\Salesforce\DataLoaderConfig Upsert_Store__c dataAccess.name=D:\Batch\Salesforce\Data\DataToSF\Store__c_20160702.csv
```

It still looks for `Store__c.csv` (apparently still wanting to use the value in the `process-conf.xml`) and not the `Store__c_20160702.csv` which I've specified on the command line.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong - is the syntax on the command line incorrect or is something else wrong with what I'm trying to do?

For those interested the requirement here is essentially to process files with a datetime suffix from a powershell script calling dataloader - and hence want to be able to parse the filename as an argument to the dataloader command (rather than using the filename hard-coded in `process-conf.xml`)

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this.  I've had a good search on google, but to no avail as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at process.bat file (for me its C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin), 
you'll see that only two parameters are supported.

Add right after if not [%2]==[] set PROCESS_OPTION=process.name=%2 (line 25)

```
if not [%3]==[] copy "%~f3" "D:\Batch\Salesforce\Data\DataToSF\Store__c.csv"
```

Now if you specify third parameter as file name, process.bat will overwrite your source

```
cmd> process.bat D:\Batch\Salesforce\DataLoaderConfig Upsert_Store__c D:\Batch\Salesforce\Data\DataToSF\Store__c_20160702.csv
```

Comment: Many thanks Ilya for showing me what the issue was.